# Change login user for SDDM under LUbuntu 18.04

Tags: login, sddm, switch-user

> SDDM is a modern display manager for X11 aiming to be fast, simple
>    and beautiful. It uses modern technologies like QtQuick to create
>    smooth, animated user interfaces.

However, my SDDM login screen always stuck with the original user created when the system was first installed -- the left and right arrow that is supposed to change the login user doesn't work for me.

This is LUbuntu 18.04.02.

Any help? Thx.

Comment: By default Lubuntu 18.04 does not use SDDM. Are you sure you're using 18.04 and not 19.04?

Comment: Well, that's a long story, for ***one*** of my machine, using the default LightDM caused the LUbuntu menu to disappear. I still haven't figure out why, so I switched to SDDM, which doesn't have that side-effect. So, yes, I'm sure I'm using 18.04, :) @DKBose

Comment: And you have more than one user set up but the login screen only shows the initial (original) user with SDDM?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the situation, @DKBose. Using LightDM allows me to type in (thus change to) the other users, and they are able to login just fine.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you but did you install all the recommends for SDDM? Maybe look at the packages listed as "suggests" as well?

Comment: No, those are irrelevant for switching login user -- sddm recommends libpam-systemd & sddm-theme and suggests libpam-kwallet5, qtvirtualkeyboard-plugin. I have libpam-systemd installed, and have also checked other packages' descriptions, as per your suggestion, but found they all are irrelevant for switching login user.

Comment: I just added `sddm` to an *pretty fresh* updated 18.04.3 LTS install; added another user and rebooted. On login `sddm` lets me select my own.user, 'qa-user' or new-user'  (QA-user would have been added for a QA-test post-install for 18.04.3).  It works for me  *This was a Xubuntu 18.04.3 QA-test install where I added updated, added `lubuntu-desktop` & `sddm` so my system will have additional packages to you*  It worked allowing me to login via other users.  Is your system fully updated? (18.04.3 came out awhile ago - http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/08/08/ubuntu-18-04-3-lts-released/)